# selinux user add becoming progressively slower

Tags: centos, selinux, optimization

I've written a service that configures a machine with selinux users who can manage a single port.  I'm trying to pre-seed that machine with 1000 users, but selinux is crawling to a halt around user 450 (only processing 6 users per hour, which is half of what it was when I started.  I've got 2 2.5ghz cpu's and 4 gb of ram on this machines.   The first time I tried this I ran out of RAM after a few hours (only had 1 gb).  Now it seems like I'm not running out of RAM, but it is getting slower and will eventually grind to a halt.

So my question is, why is selinux getting slower (specifically the semanage user command) as I add more users?  I saw a few mentions on the selinux mailing list archive about a memory leak, but it only seemed to be in esoteric places.

By request, here are all the selinux commands that I call (I know it doesn't make much sense without context), but I don't think it relevant to post my entire script.

```
    subprocess.check_call(['make', '-f', '/usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile'])
    subprocess.check_call(['checkmodule', '-M', '-m', '-o', mod_file, te_file])
    result = subprocess.check_output(['semodule_package', '-m', mod_file, '-o', pp_file])
    subprocess.check_call(['semodule', '-r', mod_name])
    return str(subprocess.check_output(['semanage', 'port', '-l', '-C', '-n'])).splitlines()
    subprocess.check_call(["semanage", "port", "-a", "-t", selinux_portname, "-p", "tcp", str(port)])
    subprocess.check_call(["chcon", "--reference", "%s/users/%s" % (selinux_context_dir, template_user), "%s/users/%s" % (selinux_context_dir, selinux_user) ])
    subprocess.check_call(["semanage", "user", "-a", "-R", selinux_role, selinux_user ])
    subprocess.check_call(["semanage", "login", "-a", "-s", selinux_user, user])
    subprocess.check_call(["restorecon", "-RF", "/home/%s" % (user)])
```

---

After running for about 40 hours, I'm up to 560 users.  But, it's leveling out at 6-7 users per hour, not sinking and not bombing out, so maybe it's as good as it gets.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @jord I added the commands I run,  the one that appears to take a longer and longer time is the semanage user -a -R "role" "user"

Comment: which CentOS version? The SELinux database is quite slow in current version. You might try Fedora with newer userspace. They claim it is a lot faster.

Comment: @jak it's Centos 7